# Inner join instead of subquery on Update query mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

can some one tell me how do I can use `inner join`, instead of the `subquery` that I did on the code below, I don't understand when you use a character for the names so pls use the names of the code.

```
UPDATE plataforma.cursos 
SET tema = ?, indice = ?, descripcion = ?, fecha = ?, idioma = ?, enlaces = ?, 
nivel = ?, keywords = ?, imagenId = (select imagenId 
                                    from imagenes 
                                    where ubicacion=?), autorId = ?,
escuelasId = ?, categoriaId = ?, subcategoriaId = ? 
WHERE idCurso =  ?;";
```

It is also prepared for php mysqli prepared query.

Edit:
Imagenes Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS imagenes(
        idImagen INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        ubicacion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(idImagen)
        )
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Cursos Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  cursos (
        idCurso INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        tema VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        indice VARCHAR(500) NULL,
        descripcion VARCHAR(250)  NULL,
        fecha DATE NOT NULL,
        idioma VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
        enlaces VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
        nivel VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
        keywords TINYTEXT NULL,
        imagenId INT NOT NULL,
        autorId INT NOT NULL,
        escuelasId INT NOT NULL,
        categoriaId INT NOT NULL,
        subcategoriaId INT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (idCurso),
        CONSTRAINT refeImagen
            FOREIGN KEY (imagenId)
            REFERENCES imagenes (idImagen)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT rauthor
            FOREIGN KEY (autorId)
            REFERENCES autores (idAutor)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT rschool
            FOREIGN KEY (escuelasId)
            REFERENCES escuelas (idEscuela)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT rctg
            FOREIGN KEY (categoriaId)
            REFERENCES categorias (idCategoria)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT rsubctg
            FOREIGN KEY (subcategoriaId)
            REFERENCES subcategorias (idSubcategoria)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ) 
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: how the two tables  are related .? . (looking to your code seems that the two table are not related   and inner join require a relation in on clause)

Comment: the field `ubicacion` exists in your table `plataforma.cursos` ?

Comment: the field ubicacion exists in table `plataforma.imagenes`  not in table  `plataforma.cursos`, in  table `plataforma.cursos` it has a field called  `imagenId` that is a foreign key @RokumDev